# Skype API for Python

Tags: python, voip, skype

I want to make an outbound call with a Skype virtual number.
I can do it in Skype app manually,
but I want to make this automatic. So I'd like to use Python to do this.
I don't know Skype provide API for this function.
Please let me know if anyone know about this.

I have tried Skpy python framework.

Comment: How did you try to use SkPy, and in what way did it not work?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)